# Извлечь данные из XML-документа в XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Имеется функция, которая тупо забирает всю страницу в виде текста:

```
function handleServerResponse() {
var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
myDiv = document.getElementById('myDivElement');
var VRegExp = new RegExp(/<pre class="data">.*<\/pre>/);
var VResult = response.match(VRegExp); 
myDiv.innerHTML = VResult;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы из response затем получить значение конкретного div, который принадлежит определенному классу, и вывести на страницу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта.

Первый это с помощью регулярного выражения. Этот вариант не будет работать если в блоке (например div) будут вложенные блоки с таким же тегом (div).

```
function handleServerResponse() {
    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
    myDiv = document.getElementById('myDivElement');
    var VRegExp = new RegExp(/<div.* class="test".*>.*<\/div>/);//регулярное выражение
    var VResult = response.match(VRegExp);//поиск строки
    myDiv.innerHTML = VResult;
}
```

Второй это просто вставить всё в невидимый блок (display:none) потом найти через DOM нужный блок и вставить значения куда нужно.

Второй вариант:

```
function handleServerResponse() {
    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
    myDiv = document.getElementById('myDivElement');
    myDiv.innerHTML = "<div style='display:none'>"+response+"</div>";
    myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.querySelector("pre.data").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: то есть из контейнера с классом pre мне так извлечь можно: var VRegExp = new RegExp(/<div.* class="test".*>.*<\/div>/);?

Comment: В данном случае я написал регулярку для того что бы выбрать тег(открытие и закрытие) и содержимое дива с классом test

Comment: @guitarhero прошу прощения. Ошибочка была. Исправил и написал возле добавленных строк что они делают

Comment: да, я там не переправил тоже) к сожалению, это не помогает :( а что обозначает ".*" в выражении?

Comment: вот чтоб более понятней было: мне надо число забрать из этих тегов и вставить в свой контейнер - <pre class="data">82</pre>

Comment: тогда попробуйте
    `var VRegExp = new RegExp(/<pre class="data">.*<\/pre>/);`

Comment: нет, это тоже не помогает..

Comment: Напишите полнотью функцию handleServerRespons

Comment: переписал сверху. может есть способ после responseXML извлечь как-нибудь?

Comment: А если сделать console.log(response ); и console.log(VResult);?

Comment: извините, я в этом днище еще >_< пока такого не умею

Comment: `function handleServerResponse() {
    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
    myDiv = document.getElementById('myDivElement');
    var VRegExp = new RegExp(/<div.* class="test".*>.*<\/div>/);//регулярное выражение
    var VResult = response.match(VRegExp);//поиск строки
    myDiv.innerHTML = VResult;
    console.log(response );
    console.log(VResult);
}`

И посмотрите в консоле что выведется и пришлите.

Comment: ух ты! О_о запомню)) в первом случае он просто текст страницы вывел, во втором null

Comment: Добавил второй вариант. Попробуйте

Comment: дядь, спасибо огромное!!! заработало! ты - кудесник! :)

Comment: Отлично. Закрывайте тогда вопрос.